# Is there a way to call base method for overloaded operators? c#

Tags: c#, inheritance, overloading, operator-keyword, radix

```
 class x : y
{
   public static bool x operator >(x i1, x i2)
   {
          // **** 
   }
}
```

Is it possible to call the > from class y in ****? If so, how?

Comment: **** means the **** in the code. y is Natural numbers, x is Integer numbers, both saved as strings... To use multiplication for instance, I would send both numbers without signal to the Natural multiplication and the signal would be the extra code for the new class

Comment: you did see my earlier comment to your earlier question in which I pointed out that Integer is not properly a subclass of Natural, didn't you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upcast `x` to `y` then you should be able to call `y`'s implementation.

```
class x : y
{
   public static bool x operator >(x i1, x i2)
   {
        bool greater = (y)i1 > (y)i2;
        return whatever;
   }
}
```

Comment: @vmp if the base class is naturals, and the derived class is integers, what happens when the integers are negative?  The naturals class can't have logic to compare negative naturals, because there is no such thing.